# Depth-2 circuits with OR and MOD gates are not universal?

Tags: complexity-theory, logic, circuits

It is well-known that every boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}$ can be realized using a boolean circuit of depth 2 (over the variables, their negation and constant values) containing AND gates in the first level and one single OR gate in the upper level; this is simply the [DNF representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) of $f$.

Another type of gate which is of great interest in circuit complexity is the $MOD_m$ gate. The usual definition is the following:

$$\mathrm{MOD}_m(x_1,\dots,x_k)=\cases{
  1 & if \(\sum x_i \equiv 0 \mod m\) \\
  0 & if \(\sum x_i \not\equiv 0 \mod m\) \\
}$$

These gates sometimes have surprising power; for example, any boolean function can be represented by a depth-2 circuit having only $\mathrm{MOD}_6$ gates (this is folklore but I can elaborate is someone is interested).

However, another folklore is that circuits with a single OR gate at the top and $\mathrm{MOD}_m$ gates in the bottom layer (with $m$ being fixed once and for all, and in particular being the same for all the gates) is not universal, i.e. for any value of $m$, there are boolean functions that cannot be computed by $\mathrm{OR} \circ \mathrm{MOD}_m$ circuit.

I'm looking for a proof for this claim, or at least some direction.

Comment: In the first paragraph, either you need NOT gates or you have to say “every _monotone_ Boolean function.”

Comment: You are correct; the usual assumption is that you have as inputs the variables, their negation and also arbitrary values (important for modgates). I'll write this explicitly.

Comment: I guess that $n$, the number of input variables, is different from $n$, the modulus?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: I am interested on this. Do you know some reference for the first folkloric fact? I wonder, if in the latter class of circuits you only allow one OR, how many do you allow in the former?

Comment: You don't need any OR gates, only two layers of MOD_6 gates. I don't have a reference but the idea is this: Any boolean function can be represented by a polynomial over Z_3 with the variables assuming the values 1 (instead of 0) and -1 (instead of 1). Note that multiplication of monomials is multiplication in the group {-1,1} which is isomorphic to Z_2, and addition of monomials is done in Z_3, so any function can be computed by a MOD_3 * MOD_2 circuit (MOD_3 in the top, MOD_2 gates in the bottom layer).

Comment: Now, it is not difficult to simulate both MOD_3 and MOD_2 gates with a MOD_6 gate: For example, MOD_3(x,y,z)=MOD_6(2x,2y,2z). There are still some small details that need to be worked out, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Juan: One nice reference (not the first) is section 3 of this paper: http://www.cs.bc.edu/~straubin/papers/modpmodm.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Boolean AND function can not be computed. Suppose actually that the AND function is computed by an $\text{OR} \circ \text{MOD}$ circuit. Then it follows that one of the MOD subcircuits must compute then AND function already, which is impossible.

Comment: No, he's correct. The implicit assumption here is that n is constant and we should be able to handle an arbitrarily large number of inputs with mod_n gates.

Comment: @GadiA Ah, ok. This wasn't clear in your question, at least to people who aren't familiar with the field. I've made a minor edit that should clarify this.

Comment: Yes, my question was very badly phrased, sorry.

Comment: @Gilles Can you explain me what fan-in here we consider ? The problem for me is that I can't see why subcircuit of MOD can't compute AND ? How many inputs has this MOD and this AND ?